# I want to swap row condition wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analysis

We have  4 column Credit, Debit, narration, and Balance.In credit column amount will be credit in to Balance column
And Debit column amount will be Debited from Balance column. I give a one datafarme for reference

```
   Narration  Credit  Debit  Balance
1  Abc         15.0    Nan    15.0
2  Qwe         NaN     5.0    10.0 
3  Wer         NaN     2.0     7.0  
4  opr         Nan     3.0     5.0
5  Yur         6.0     NaN    11.0
```

I have datafarme like this but on this 3 and 4 index Debit amount not matched with Balance value so i want datafarme that can be match with Balance..

```
  Narration  Credit  Debit  Balance
1  Abc         15.0    Nan    15.0
2  Qwe         NaN     5.0    10.0 
3  opr         NaN     3.0     7.0  
4  wer         Nan     2.0     5.0
5  Yur         6.0     NaN    11.0
```

I want datafarme that can be matched with Credit Debit value. it's only 5 row for example i have 500 rows so i can I check balance is matched with Credit Debit amount .

Comment: what do you mean by 'matched'?

Comment: If amount credit then balance value will be plus and Debit then it will minus from Balance value

Comment: I think he means that balance for row 2 is 10, in row 3 there is 2 debit and the balance is 7, when it should be 8, or the debit should be 3 (the row 4).

Comment: Pleas share the expected output

Comment: I shared 2nd datafarme that i won't this

Comment: What's the difference between your 2nd dataframe and your first one?

Comment: Value of debit amount

Comment: Can't you just fix your balance amount, like my answer?

Comment: No.. balance value doesn't change

Comment: See new answer @jainamshah

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want: `Series.diff` and `np.where`.

We get the difference between each row in `Balance` and if this difference is `< 0` then we take the `absolute` and assign it to `Debit`

```
mapping_debit = df.dropna(subset=['Debit']).set_index('Debit')['Narration']
mapping_credit = df.dropna(subset=['Credit']).set_index('Credit')['Narration']

balance = df['Balance'].diff().fillna(df['Credit']).fillna(df['Debit'])

df['Credit'] = np.where(balance.ge(0), balance, np.NaN)
df['Debit'] = np.where(balance.lt(0), balance.abs(), np.NaN)

df['Narration'] = df['Debit'].map(mapping_debit).fillna(df['Credit'].map(mapping_credit))

  Narration  Credit  Debit  Balance
0       Abc    15.0    NaN     15.0
1       Qwe     NaN    5.0     10.0
2       Wer     NaN    3.0      7.0
3       opr     NaN    2.0      5.0
4       Yur     6.0    NaN     11.0
```

Note that we have to import `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
```

Comment: No doubt want this balance doesn't change

Comment: If credit amount not matched with balance then...i won't i combine condition for this ....

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you try to say. @jainamshah

Comment: If same problems accure in Credit then what can i do??

Comment: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the below which uses `np.select` and `df.mask()` with a few conditions:

```
s=df['Credit'].fillna(df['Balance']).diff().abs()
cond1=s.ne(df['Debit'])
cond2=s.eq(df['Debit'].shift(-1))
cond3=s.shift().eq(df['Debit'])

values=np.select([(cond1[:,None]&cond2[:,None]),(cond1[:,None]&cond3[:,None])],
          [df.shift(-1),df.shift()])

final=df.mask(cond1&(cond2|cond3),values)
final['Balance']=df['Balance']
```

---

```
  Narration Credit Debit  Balance
1       Abc     15   NaN     15.0
2       Qwe    NaN     5     10.0
3       opr    NaN     3      7.0
4       Wer    NaN     2      5.0
5       Yur      6   NaN     11.0
```

Comment: if the required value after three rows then how can I shift the value..

Comment: replace `shift(-1)` with `shift(-2)` and `shift()` with `shift(2)` and try? @jainamshah

Comment: @jainamshah you have to also take care of the `diff` I gues, but that should be a different question I believe